# Calculate the partitions of N

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, combinatorics, integer-partitions

Your challenge is simple: GIven an integer **N**, ouput every list of positive integers that sums to **N**. For example, if the input was 5, you should output

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[5]
```

These lists do not have to be output in any particular order, nor do the numbers inside each list. For example, this would also be an acceptable output for '5':

```
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[5]
[3, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[4, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 3]
```

You can safely assume that the input will be a positive integer, and you can take this number in any reasonable format.

**You may NOT use any builtin functions that do this.**

If your program either fails or takes too long for large **N** this is OK, but you must at the very least produce the correct output for the first 15.

Standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Test IO

```
1:
[[1]]

2:
[[1, 1], [2]]

3:
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [3]]

4:
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [4]]

5:
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 4], [2, 3], [5]]

7:
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 3], [1, 6], [2, 2, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [7]]

10:
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 5], [1, 1, 1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 7], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 6], [1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 4, 4], [1, 1, 8], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 7], [1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 9], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 3, 3], [2, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 4], [2, 8], [3, 3, 4], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 5], [10]]
```

Super large test case: 15 should output this

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 8], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8], [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 11], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 8], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2, 10], [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 6], [1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 1, 1, 3, 9], [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 4, 8], [1, 1, 1, 5, 7], [1, 1, 1, 6, 6], [1, 1, 1, 12], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6], [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5], [1, 1, 2, 2, 9], [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 1, 2, 11], [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 3, 3, 7], [1, 1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 1, 3, 5, 5], [1, 1, 3, 10], [1, 1, 4, 4, 5], [1, 1, 4, 9], [1, 1, 5, 8], [1, 1, 6, 7], [1, 1, 13], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 2, 8], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 2, 4, 6], [1, 2, 2, 5, 5], [1, 2, 2, 10], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 9], [1, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 5, 7], [1, 2, 6, 6], [1, 2, 12], [1, 3, 3, 3, 5], [1, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 3, 3, 8], [1, 3, 4, 7], [1, 3, 5, 6], [1, 3, 11], [1, 4, 4, 6], [1, 4, 5, 5], [1, 4, 10], [1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 8], [1, 7, 7], [1, 14], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 3, 6], [2, 2, 2, 4, 5], [2, 2, 2, 9], [2, 2, 3, 3, 5], [2, 2, 3, 4, 4], [2, 2, 3, 8], [2, 2, 4, 7], [2, 2, 5, 6], [2, 2, 11], [2, 3, 3, 3, 4], [2, 3, 3, 7], [2, 3, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5, 5], [2, 3, 10], [2, 4, 4, 5], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7], [2, 13], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 6], [3, 3, 4, 5], [3, 3, 9], [3, 4, 4, 4], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 7], [3, 6, 6], [3, 12], [4, 4, 7], [4, 5, 6], [4, 11], [5, 5, 5], [5, 10], [6, 9], [7, 8], [15]]
```

#### Catalog

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 84165; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 31716; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/46991/random-golf-of-the-day-3-integer-partitions

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *handle*?

Comment: @flawr I disagree - finding all partitions is sufficiently different from finding strict partitions. However, [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66159/find-the-sets-of-sums) might be a dupe target.

Comment: I think looking for unordered partitions and not limiting the number of parts makes this different enough.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *buitin*?

Comment: @LeakyNun If your language has a function that takes an integer *N* and returns all lists that sum to N, you may not use this function.

Comment: How about 0's, can we pad the  list with 0's say up to the length of N?

Comment: @MickyT I'm gonna say no. Your outputs should match mine. (Although the order can be different)

Comment: Are duplicate lists allowed in the output?

Comment: @Zgarb no, that is not allowed.

Comment: the no dupes makes it really annoying..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Pyth, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
{SMlMM./U
```

Not too sure if this isn't cheating, but the rules only said one cannot use **integer** partition (it's not stated clearly in the question itself, but a comment by OP in the question says integer partition). I'm using <s>string</s> **list** partition, which makes slices of the list that concatenate up to the "mother" list. I believe I have to thank @Maltysen for the idea of using lists rather than strings.

n=15 takes less than one second on my machine.

In dataflow pseudocode:

```
              input       // initial data
        U     range       // makes a list of length equal to input
      ./      partition   // partitions string
   lMM        length      // length of each substring in each way to partition
 SM           sort        // sort each way to partition
{             deduplicate // removes all duplicate after sorting
              print       // implicit, output final result
```

[Try it online here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BSMlMM.%2FU&input=4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A7%0A10%0A15&debug=0)

Comment: `{mSlMd./*N` saves a byte

Comment: You can go for 7 bytes if you use list partitioning instead of string partition: http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sMM.%2Fm1&input=5&debug=0

Comment: @LeakyNun Well I actually tried and it didn't save a byte. When I saw your comment tho, I found out that my answer was actually 10 bytes, so I actually miscounted (forgot gedit blocks start from 1).

Comment: @Maltysen You need to sort each sub-list, and then deduplicate.

Comment: @Maltysen You were right, using lists does shorten it. I tried adding sort and deduplicate to the code you linked to and it didn't help, but it's all thanks to you that I got the idea of replacing *N with U. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
L?b{SM+R-bsdsyMb]Y
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3Fb%7BSM%2BR-bsdsyMb%5DYy&input=15&debug=0) (The `y` at the end is used to call the function)

This is fairly quick.

This uses recursion. If the input is `b`, my method will generate the partitions from `0` to `b-1`, and then generate the correct partitions from each.

For example, when `b=4`:

- `b=0` gives `[[]]`
- `b=1` gives `[[1]]`
- `b=2` gives `[[2], [1, 1]]`
- `b=3` gives `[[3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 1]]`

Then, to each partition in `b=0`, append `4` (to make the sum 4); to each partition in `b=1`, append `3` (to make the sum `4`); etc.

This is mainly how it works.

```
L?b{SM+R-bsdsyMb]Y

L                    define a function called "y" which takes an argument: "b"
 ?b                  test for truthiness of b (in this case, test if b>0).


   {SM+R-bsdsyMb     if truthy:

             yMb         call this function from 0 to b-1.
            s            unpack each list of partitions, generating only partitions.
      +R                 to each partition (d), append:
        -                    the difference of
         b                   b (the argument) and
          sd                 the sum of d (the partition).
    SM                   sort each partition.
   {                     remove duplicates.


                ]Y   if falsey:

                 Y       yield [].
                ]        yield [[]].
```

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 53 bytes

```hs
p=[[]]:[map(1:)q++[a+1:b|a:b<-q,all(a<)b]|q<-p]
(p!!)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
:"0Gq:@XNG3$Yc!dS!Xu
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiIwR3E6QFhORzMkWWMhZFMhWHU&input=NQ)

For input `15` it takes about 2 seconds in the online compiler.

#### Explanation

This works by generating partition *points* and then converting to partition *lengths*. What I mean by this is the following. Given input *N* = 5, a possible partition is [2 2 1]. This is represented by partition points [0 2 4 5], such that *consecutive differences* (or lengths) of the partition points give the resulting partition of the input number.

All arrays of partition points start with 0 and end with *N*. The number *k* of intermediate points  varies from 0 to *N*-1. For *N* and *k* given, the intermediate points can be generated as a combination of the numbers [1, 2, ..., *N*-1] taken *k* at a time.

Several arrays of partition points may give rise to the same result in a different order. For example, partition points [0 1 3 5] would give the partition lengths [1 2 2], i.e. the same as the previous [2 2 1] only in a different order. This has to be taken into account by *sorting* each array of partition lengths and *removing duplicates*.

```
:        % Implicitly input N. Push [1 2 ... N]. These are the possible values of k,
         % except with N instead of 0
"        % For each
  0      %   Push 0
  Gq:    %   Push [1 ... N-1]. These the possible intermediate points
  @XN    %   Push k and produce the combinations. Each k produces a 2D array with
         %   each combination on a row. The value k=N produces an empty array
  G      %   Push N
  3$Yc   %   Prepend a column of zeros and append a column of N to the array
  !d     %   Transpose. Consecutive differences of each column
  S!     %   Sort each column. Transpose
  Xu     %   Keep only unique rows
         % Implicitly end for and display all arrays in the stack
```

Comment: Nice, the concept of partition points is a very clever way to solve this.

Comment: @Nick Thank you! And welcome to (being active in) this site! :-)

Answer (score 5):

## J, <s>49</s> <s>42</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```
a:1&([:~.@,(,;}./:~@,(+{.))&>)~]
```

It's tacit now!

Builds the integer partition of *n* by constructing the integer partitions from 1 to *n*. Computes the result for *n* = 15 in a millisecond.

Starting with the initial integer partition `[[1]]` which corresponds to *n* = 1, construct the next integer partition by joining the results from two operations: appending a 1 to each partition; incrementing the smallest value by 1 in each partition. Of course, duplicate partitions will be removed. To get the integer partition *n* = 2 and onwards,

```
Partition for n = 1
[[1]]

Partition for n = 2
[[1, 1]] join [[2]]
= [[1, 1], [2]]

Partition for n = 3
[[1, 2], [1, 1, 1]] join [[3], [1, 2]]
= [[3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 1]]

... and so on
```

### Usage

```
   f =: a:1&([:~.@,(,;}./:~@,(+{.))&>)~]
   f 1
┌─┐
│1│
└─┘
   f 2
┌───┬─┐
│1 1│2│
└───┴─┘
   f 3
┌─────┬───┬─┐
│1 1 1│1 2│3│
└─────┴───┴─┘
   f 5
┌─────────┬───────┬─────┬───┬─────┬───┬─┐
│1 1 1 1 1│1 1 1 2│1 2 2│2 3│1 1 3│1 4│5│
└─────────┴───────┴─────┴───┴─────┴───┴─┘
   # f 15
176
```

### Explanation

Since J does not support ragged arrays, each partition has to be boxed so they they won't be zero padded when appended to other partitions.

```
a:1&([:~.@,(,;}./:~@,(+{.))&>)~]  Input: n
a:                                The empty box
                               ]  Get the input n
  1&(                        )~   Repeat n times with an initial array of one empty box
           (              )&>       Operate on each partition
                     (   )            Hook a partition
                       {.               Get its head (the smallest value)
  1                   +                 Add 1 to it
  1           }.                      Drop the first value in each partition
                    ,                 Join the previous two results
                /:~@                  Sort it
  1         ,                         Prepend a 1 to the initial partition
             ;                        Box the last two results and join them
     [:   ,                         Flatten the pairs of boxes
       ~.@                          Remove duplicates and return
                                  Return the final result where each box
                                  is a partition of n
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 65 bytes

**Python 3**

```python
def f(n,i=1,l=[]):n or print(l);i>n or[f(n-i,i,[i]+l),f(n,i+1,l)]
```

This function accumulates a partition and prints the outputs, branching on choices. It decides how many 1's to put in the partition, how many 2's, and so on. For each value `i`, it either

- Adds a part of size `i`, and decreases `n` to `n-i`, or
- Moves on to `i+1`

If `i>n`, then no more parts can be made, so it stops. If `n` falls to `0`, the partition is successful and so is printed.

**Python 2**

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:n/i and[l+[i]for l in f(n-i,i)]+f(n,i+1)or[[]][n:]
```

A recursive method that outputs a list of partitions. As with the Python 3 code, it counts up the part size `i` and decides at each step whether to add another part of size `i` or stop.

Both of these do `n=15` almost instantly.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, 194 bytes

```
p=n=>{var a=[];for(var i=1;i<=n-i;i+=1){for(v of p(n-i)){v.push(i);a.push(v.sort())}}a.push([n]);return a};n=5;s=p(n).map(v=>JSON.stringify(v));s=s.filter((v,i)=>s.indexOf(v)==i);console.log(s);
```

**Non-minified**

Finding uniques by sorting and comparing to a string is quite a hack, but probably saves space.

```
p = n => {
    var a = [];
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= n-i; i++)
    {
        for (v of p(n-i)) {
            v.push(i);
            a.push(v.sort());
        }
    }

    a.push([n]);

    return a;
}

n = 5;
s = p(n).map(v =>  JSON.stringify(v));
s = s.filter((v,i) => s.indexOf(v) == i);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: `Quite a hack but saves space` That's exactly what this site is about. :D

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```haskell
0%m=[[]]
n%m=[j:r|j<-[m..n],r<-(n-j)%j]
(%1)
```

The auxiliary function `n%m` gives the partitions of `n` into parts `≥m`, with the main function using `m=1`. It branches of each first entry `j` with `m≤j≤n`, recursing on the remaining partition of `n-j` into parts that are at least `j`. The base case `n==0` gives just the empty partition.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5, <s>82</s> 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:{(*sorted([*p,i]),)for i in range(1,n)for p in f(n-i)}|{(n,)}
```

Returns a set of tuples. **n = 15** finishes instantly.

Test it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/C7rf/3).

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 33 bytes (Non-competing)

```
:1f:oad.
:1eI,.##lI,.:{.>0}a+?,.=
```

This is non-competing because of a bug fix.

This takes about 1 second for `15` on my machine. For `20` and greater this crashes with an `Out of global stack` exception.

#### Explanation

This uses no partitioning built-in of any kind, and instead uses the fact that `+` works both ways through constraints propagation.

- Main predicate:

  ```
  :1f                       Find the list of all valid outputs of predicate 1
     :oa                    Sort each element of that list
        d.                  Output is that list of sorted lists minus all duplicates
  ```
- Predicate 1:

  ```
  :1eI                      I is an integer between Input and 1
      .##lI,                Output is a list of length I
            .:{.>0}a        Elements of Output are integers greater than 0
                    +?,     The sum of the elements of Output is Input
                       .=   Assign values to the elements of Output
  ```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>62</s> 54 bytes

```
Inner[#2~Table~#&,FrobeniusSolve[r=Range@#,#],r,Join]&
```

The partitions of an integer *n* can be found by solving for *n*-tuples of non-negative integers (*c*<sub>1</sub>, *c*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *c*<sub>*n*</sub>) such that *c*<sub>1</sub> + 2 *c*<sub>2</sub> + ... + *n* *c*<sub>*n*</sub> = *n*. `FrobeniusSolve` is able to find all solutions to this equation which are used to create that many copies of their respective values in order to find all integer partitions of *n*.

Comment: ... and how is this not a built-in?

Comment: @LeakyNun `FrobeniusSolve` does not find integer partitions, it finds all solutions *of non-negative integers*  `x1 ... xN` to equations of the form `a1 x1 + a2 x2 + ... aN xN = b` given `a1 ... aN` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
L|{SMs+LVrb0yMb]Y
```

Defines a function named `y`.  [Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%7C%7BSMs%2BLVrb0yMb%5DYy&input=5&test_suite_input=5).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
b1ŒṖḅ1Ṣ€Q
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YjHFkuG5luG4hTHhuaLigqxR&input=&args=MTU)

#### How it works

```
b1ŒṖḅ1Ṣ€Q  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

b1         Convert n to unary, i.e., a list A of n 1's.
  ŒṖ       Generate all partitions of the list A.
    ḅ1     Convert each flat list from unary to integer.
      Ṣ€   Sort each resulting list.
        Q  Unique; deduplicate the lists.
```

Answer (score 1):

### J, 39 bytes

```
[:~.i.<@\:~@(#;.1~"1 0)1,@{@;(<1 0)#~<:
```

This is a monadic verb that takes an integer and returns an array of boxed arrays. [Try it here.](http://tryj.tk/) Usage:

```
   p =: [:~.i.<@\:~@(#;.1~"1 0)1,@{@;(<1 0)#~<:
   p 3
+-----+---+-+
|1 1 1|2 1|3|
+-----+---+-+
```

On input 15, it runs for about a second on my machine.

### Explanation

This challenge immediately looked like a job for Catalogue (`{`) and Cut (`;.`).
The outline of the algorithm is:

- Produce all 0-1 arrays of length `n`.
- For each of them, cut a dummy length-`n` array along the 1s, and list the lengths of each part.
- Sort the lengths, and remove duplicate arrays from the result.

Apparently, Luis Mendo had the [same idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84169/32014) too.

Explanation of code:

```
[:~.i.<@\:~@(#;.1~"1 0)1,@{@;(<1 0)#~<:   Input is n.
                                     <:   n-1
                                   #~     copies of
                             (<1 0)       the boxed array [1 0].
                       1    ;             Prepend the boxed array [1].
                          {@              Catalog: produces all combinations of taking one
                                          item from each box, in a high-dimensional matrix.
                        ,@                Flatten the matrix. This results in a list of all
                                          boxed 0-1 arrays of length n that begin with a 1.
    i.                                    The array A =: 0, 1, ..., n-1.
            (     "1 0)                   For each of the boxed arrays B:
              ;.1~                          cut A along the occurrences of 1s in B,
             #                              take the length of each part,
        \:~@                                sort the lengths,
      <@                                    and put the result in a box.
[:~.                                      Remove duplicate boxes.
```

Comment: Very nice use of cut `;.` again.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ɾÞ×'∑?=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvsOew5cn4oiRPz0iLCIiLCI1Il0=)

```
ɾÞ×'∑?=
ɾ       # Get a list in the range [1, input]
 Þ×     # Get all combinations (with replacement) of all lengths
   '    # Filter for:
    ∑?= #  Sum equals the input
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript <s>(Firefox 30-57) 79</s> ES6, 65 bytes

```
f=(n,m=1,a=[])=>n?m>n?[]:[...f(n-m,m,[...a,m]),...f(n,m+1,a)]:[a]
```

Port of @xnor's Python solution. (If only I'd noticed that you could recurse over `m` as well as `n`...)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Å1.œO€{ê
```

Outputs as a list of lists, from `n` amount of 1s to `[n]`, where each inner list is sorted (I know the rules allow them to be unsorted, but it's necessary for the uniquify of lists).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKuh3tHJ/o@a1lQfXvX/v6EpAA) or [verify the first 15 result](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o6qrkmVdQWmKloGTvp8Ol5F9aAuHp@P0/3Gqod3Sy/6OmNdWHV/3XObTN/j8A).

If builtins were allowed, this would be **2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead (with the same exact results):
`Åœ` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvRyf//G5oCAA) or [verify the first 15 results](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o6qrkmVdQWmKloGTvp8Ol5F9aAuHp@P0/3Hp08n@dQ9vs/wMA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Å1        # Push a list with the (implicit) input amount of 1s
  .œ      # Get all partitions of this list
    O     # Sum each inner-most list
     €{   # Sort each inner list
       ê  # Sorted uniquify the list of lists
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Minor note: `ê` (sorted uniquify) could also just be `Ù` (uniquify) for the same result, but with the added sort it's a lot faster in this case.

Comment: Apparently it's the exact same approach as [*@Dennis*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84189/52210) I now notice. I came up with it independently just yet, but it's not too surprising we're using the same straight-forward approach, being codegolf languages with these builtins available.

Answer (score 0):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 44 bytes

```
(1!)
_!0=[]
a!n=anyOf[a ..n]#n
a#n=a:a!(n-a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z/NVsNQUZMrXtHANjqWK1ExzzYxr9I/LTpRQU8vL1Y5jytRGShklaiokaebqPk/NzEzT8FWIU3B9D8A)

Answer (score 0):

### [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 117 bytes

Port of [@Dennis's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84187/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxC8IwEEZ3f8WNOYqBDC6VCI4OnTqWIrG9QCRe0@YEQfztMQ5u33t8vDy56Mpyu9Mk0LnAQC8hnjOcU3pDmcmDV9xeWLDtSYae1qHCONpQvbUGq1XVKoNIMZMy8GQJERi1j046l1Swp3reB9SPSte2@S@dl01oRtSy1E7z6zAWgLQFlsjKK3NAPO4@5Qs)

```scala
def f(n:Int):Set[Seq[Int]]=if(n==1)Set(Seq(1))else(1 until n).flatMap(i=>f(n-i).map(_:+i).map(_.sorted)).toSet+Seq(n)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xCoMwEIZ3n@IfE6RChi4WCx0LdeooDqkmkJKewVyhID67VSvS4eDuvo@7Pzba62nqHk/TMErtCObDhtqISwgDEqA1FlZQjiuxzHE3XN1c5Goe6xoFhtkBnIUgFAWU3DZYVLGoQkm5rkYYH83OhcKb2HmQzKzXXOqAAQ7FeROwPMYBTmavlYV/Nh8IyNOFxq5n0@5k3Lox424OgRRrDNpSJL8KvSP2JKxQRylPyThNXw)

```scala
object Main extends App{ 
  def f(n: Int): Set[List[Int]] = {
    if (n == 1) {
      Set(List(1))
    } else {
      (1 until n).flatMap { i =>
        f(n - i).map { p =>
          (p :+ i).sorted
        }
      }.toSet + List(n)
    }
  }
  println(f(15));
}
```