# Restricted Integer Partitions

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, integer-partitions

\$P_k(n)\$ means the number of partitions of \$n\$ into exactly \$k\$ positive parts. Given \$n\$ and \$k\$, calculate \$P_k(n)\$.

> Tip: \$P_k(n) = P_k(n−k) + P_{k−1}(n−1)\$, with initial values \$P_0(0) = 1\$ and \$P_k(n) = 0\$ if \$n \leq 0\$ or \$k \leq 0\$. <sup>[[Wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts)</sup>

## Examples

```
n    k    Ans
1    1    1
2    2    1
4    2    2
6    2    3
10   3    8
```

## Rules

- General [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Comment: Can someone link to the OEIS for this (I assume there is one with the number of partition sequences we've been running into on the CnR OEIS post)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84165/calculate-the-partitions-of-n)

Comment: [A008284](http://oeis.org/A008284)

Comment: Is restricting the second input, `k`, to non-negative integers is acceptable? Also should the solution work for negative `n`? Zero `n`? (my guesses are yes, yes, and yes)

Comment: If `k` is fixed the generating function for this is `x^k/((1-x)*(1-x^2)*...*(1-x^k))`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't see how `k` can be negative, given it's the length of a partition.

Comment: This needs more detail. Can 0 be a partition element? Can a partition contain duplicates? Do we count only increasing partitions?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer there are, by the very definition provided in the OP, `0` partitions for `k<=0`. (and my guess to the answer to my question was "yes" too)

Comment: @Zgarb it could help to add such information to the post, yes. But to address these questions "an integer partition is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers. Two sums that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition.", so: no zeros inside; duplicates are acceptable; disregard order for counting. (Note that `P(0,0)` is `1` however - one way to have the empty set).

Comment: In the tip, if `P0(0)=1`, shouldn't the condition in the other case be `<0` instead of `≤ 0`?

Comment: @JAD No, ≤ is correct, it's just that "if both are not zero" is missing.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>61</s> <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer. -1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder.*

I will say, I did copy the hint from OP and translate it to Python. :P

```python
P=lambda n,k:n*k>0and P(n-k,k)+P(n-1,k-1)or+(n==k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCoMwEATQe75ij1ldwaSlByF@g/fiIcWWhm03EnPp16dWKTinBwMz8yc/o9hSBvfy79vkQYg7qbhvvUwwaGmYGOsfDHFjMKZai3OMJd@XvICDq4I12hAYpN2WwP59PvhysGkJTqhGpR4xQYAgsC12Wz2nIHn9rwKWLw)

Comment: This breaks on the last test case of 10, 3. Too much recursion

Comment: @jkelm Fixed. -

Comment: `(n>0and k>0)` -> `n>0<k`

Comment: Heh, nice abuse of Python's comparison operators. I wish there was a way to have the 0 at the end though, so I could get rid of that space...

Comment: Also you can do `+(n==k)` instead of `[0,1][n==k]`.

Comment: You don't need the space in `or +`.

Comment: "*I will say, I did copy the hint from OP and translate it to Python*" - I don't feel so bad that my solution ended up being so similar to yours, now!

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8A2JzE3KSVRIU8n2ypPK9vOIDEvRSFAI083WydbUxvEMNTJ1jXUzC/S1siztc3W/F9QlJlXAlRiqKNgqMkF4xnpKBgheCYoPDMUnqGBjoKx5n8A), replace `n>0<k and` with `n*k>0and`

Comment: (also @EriktheOutgolfer) What is the `+` in `+(n==k)` for exactly? [This](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCsIwEATQe75ijk3dQjeKh0L8ht7FQ6SKYXVb2lz8@hgrQuf0YGBmeqfHqC7n3j/D6zoEKEmntZzaoAP6ShshsbsvmKRhO85Q7yWn25IWeJwNSiomsKWfHcH9fdj4uDG3hL01F2PuZTEiKtbFbq2nOWoq73W0@QM) seems to work for 48.

Comment: To cast `n==k` to an integer. Technically, `True` instead of 1 and `False` instead of 0 is allowed but it shaves off 3 bytes and is just... meh.

Comment: @JonathanAllan `+` converts `True`/`False` to `0`/`1`

Comment: Does it ever need to be cast though, wont the addition in the pre-tail call always exist, hence casting any boolean results to integers?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Not always.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer right - if numbers less than 1 are required to be handled I suppose.

Comment: @totallyhuman nothing is "just ...meh" when it comes to shaving off bytes ;p

Answer (score 4):

## [Swift](https://www.swift.org), <s>76</s> 73 bytes

```swift
func P(_ n:Int,_ k:Int)->Int{return n*k>0 ?P(n-k,k)+P(n-1,k-1):n==k ?1:0}
```

[Try it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5978b4a324f31b189780f907)

---

## Explanation

#### How does the code structurally work?

First of all, we define our function `P`, with two integer parameters `n` and `k`, and give it a return type of `Int`, with this piece of code: `func P(_ n:Int,_ k:Int)->Int{...}`. The cool trick here is that we tell the compiler to ignore the names of the parameters, with `_` followed by a space, which saves us two bytes when we call the function. `return` is obviously used to return the result of our nested ternary described below.

Another trick I used was `n*k>0`, which saves us a couple of bytes over `n>0&&k>0`. If the condition is true (both the integers are still higher than `0`), then we recursively call our function with `n` decremented by `k` as our new `n` and `k` stays the same, and we add the result of `P()` with `n` and `k` decremented by 1. If the condition is not true, we return either `1` or `0` depending on whether `n` is equal to `k`.

#### How does the recursive algorithm work?

We know that the first element of the sequence is **p<sub>0</sub>(0)**, and so we check that both integers are positive (`n*k>0`). If they are not higher than 0, we check if they are equal (`n==l ?1:0`), here being two cases:

- There is exactly 1 possible partition, and thus we return 1, if the integers are equal.
- There are no partitions if one of them is already 0 and the other is not.

However, if both are positive, we recursively call `P` twice, adding the results of `P(n-k,k)` and `P(n-1,k-1)`. And we loop again until `n` has reached 0.

---

<sub>* *Note:* The spaces cannot be removed.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>9</strike> <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)!</sup>

```
/lM./E
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FlM.%2FE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A1%0A%0A2%0A2%0A%0A2%0A4%0A%0A2%0A6%0A%0A3%0A10%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

Inputs to the program are reversed (i.e. `k, n`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
œċS€ċ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5CPdwY@a1hzpftS44////4YG/40B)

Comment: Ah ha, of course!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
Length@IntegerPartitions[#,{#2}]&
```

here is n x k table

```
 \k->
 n1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
 |1  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
 v1  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
  1  2  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  
  1  2  2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0  
  1  3  3   2   1   1   0   0   0   0  
  1  3  4   3   2   1   1   0   0   0  
  1  4  5   5   3   2   1   1   0   0  
  1  4  7   6   5   3   2   1   1   0  
  1  5  8   9   7   5   3   2   1   1
```

Comment: Of course. I knew there was a builtin.

Comment: A [Mathematica Simplified](https://github.com/1ekf/Mathematica-Simplified) port would save a 13 bytes here I believe (`Length`->``Len`1`` and `IntegerPartitions` -> ``Int`7``

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm actually making a super-short version of this. Hopefully I can finish it by the end of the month

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
y:Z^!S!Xu!Xs=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v9IqKk4xWDGiVDGi2Lb4/39DAy5jAA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `6`, `2`.

```
y     % Implicitly take the two inputs. Duplicate from below
      % STACK: 6, 2, 6
:     % Range
      % STACK: 6, 2, [1 2 3 4 5 6]
Z^    % Cartesian power
      % STACK: 6, [1 1; 1 2; ... 1 5; 1 6; 2 1; 2 2; ...; 6 6]
!S!   % Sort each row
      % STACK: 6, [1 1; 1 2; ... 1 5; 1 6; 1 2; 2 2; ...; 6 6]
Xu    % Unique rows
      % STACK: 6, [1 1; 1 2; ... 1 5; 1 6; 2 2; ...; 6 6]
!Xs   % Sum of each row, as a row vector
      % STACK: 6, [2 3 ... 6 7 4 ... 12]
=     % Equals, element-wise
      % STACK: [0 0 ... 1  0 0 ... 0]
s     % Sum. Implicitly display
      % STACK: 3
```

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised MATL doesn't have an "integer partition" builtin or something.

Comment: @Sanchises It should be working now. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: No problem. I was just playing with it to understand your method (which is generally easier for small cases) when I ran into the error.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 39 bytes

I think this works.

```js
f=(x,y)=>x*y>0?f(x-y,y)+f(--x,--y):x==y
```

---

### Try it

```js
k.value=(
f=(x,y)=>x*y>0?f(x-y,y)+f(--x,--y):x==y
)(i.value=10,j.value=3)
onchange=_=>k.value=f(+i.value,+j.value)
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif}input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:100px;}#j,#k{width:50px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>n: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>k: </label><input id=j type=number><label for=k>P<sub>k</sub>(n): </label><input id=k readonly>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 41 bytes

```
0#0=1
n#k|n*k>0=(n-k)#k+(n-1)#(k-1)
_#_=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30DZwNaQK085uyZPK9vOwFYjTzdbUzlbG0gbaiprZANJrnjleFuD/7mJmXkKtgoFRZl5JQoqCoYGCsoKxgr/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 35 bytes

[Pari/GP has a built-in for iterating over integer partitions.](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Programming_in_GP__control_statements.html#forpart)

```
n->k->i=0;forpart(x=n,i++,,[k,k]);i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y5b1y7T1sA6Lb@oILGoRKPCNk8nU1tbRyc6Wyc7VtM6839BUWZeiUaahqEmEGlywbhGmkCE4Jqgcs1QuYYGmhrGmpr/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```c
f(n,k){n=n*k>0?f(n-k,k)+f(--n,--k):n&k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7BCsIwDAbge59CBkqjLbTdGGJR8T16kUpllAXR3saevXbdYdaFXJJ8/MTyp7UxOorMw4Bn3PuLuKaR@7Q4OMo5Ms49nHDn9Rj7e4cUyEA2qV7vDoOjFZrgTbjhx4Q5yGAFuiDShLm3j3RkjkomAfRECqdMUIVTTMFfVpONWkyzNm0G9WLatZEii@PPU4LVkxpJ/AI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
n&0=0^n
n&k=sum$map(&(k-1))[n-1,n-k-1..0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0/NwNYgLo8rTy3btrg0VyU3sUBDTSNb11BTMzpP11AnTxfI1tMziP2fm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioGFooKCmYKz5HwA)

An alternate recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅœIùg
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvRyZ6Hd6b//29owGUMAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6P/DrUcnRxzemf5f5390tKGOYaxOtJGOEZA0AZNmYNLQQMc4NhYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ     # Get all lists of positive integers that sum to the first (implicit) 
       # input-integer `n`
   ù   # Only keep the lists with a length equal to
  I    # the second input-integer `k`
    g  # Pop and push the length to get the amount of remaining lists
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

I <s>have a feeling</s> [know](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135878/53748) this basic approach **won't** be the golfiest!

```
RŒṖL€€Ṣ€QṀ€=S
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o6KSHO6f5PGpaA0QPdy4CkoEPdzYAKdvg////Gxr8NwYA)**

Comment: Yeah it isn't (see my Jelly answer at the far bottom).

Comment: Oh no Code bowling

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer If it works why is it deleted?

Comment: @Jonathan refresh

Comment: @JonathanAllan It was deleted before a test case was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
L²ã€{ÙO¹¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f8wNWFiMWX//0zCssOj4oKse8OZT8K5wqL//zEwCjM)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 18 bytes

```
{_,:)@m*:$_&::+e=}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Ol7HStMhV8tKJV7Nyko71bb2f91/YwVDAwA)

Expects inputs in reverse, i.e. `k n` instead of `n k`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 98 bytes

Well this is some easy unreworked use of OP's tip.

`k` and `n` are the parameters of my recursive function `f`.

```scala
def f(n:Int,k:Int):Int={(k,n)match{case(0,0)=>1
case _ if k<1|n<1=>0
case _=>f(n-k,k)+f(n-1,k-1)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc2xCsIwEAbgPU9xdEowhaSWDtIEHB18BolpijU1FptBqH32mIBau/z8dx/cjVr1KtzPV6M9HFXnwDy9cc0I@2GYUGhMCy12u4Pz1KYkKcSELXXkpry@TFqNBjPKiJAcpQFO0LVga/5yNReSfZZCxkO5pZZsUuHU5pzMc0DDo3O@dzjjlEMuIYseKyGLFLT4Sqz/Ui5SrqVapFoLZ3T7exR7NDSHNw)

Comment: This is invalid as it's a snippet, not a proper function.

Answer (score 1):

## R (+ pryr), 49 bytes

```
f=pryr::f(`if`(k<1|n<1,!n+k,f(n-k,k)+f(n-1,k-1)))
```

Which evaluates to the recursive function

```
function (k, n) 
if (k < 1 | n < 1) !n + k else f(n - k, k) + f(n - 1, k - 1)
```

`(k < 1 | n < 1)` checks if any of the initial states are met. `!n + k` evaluates to TRUE (1) if both `n` and `k` are 0, and FALSE (0) otherwise. `f(n - k, k) + f(n - 1, k - 1)` handles the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex  (Perl/PCRE+`(?^=)`<sup><sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup></sup>), <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```
^((?^=(\2?x))(\1|^x)x*)+,\2$
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Restricted-Integer-Partitions-PCRE) (RegexMathEngine)

Takes its input in unary, as the lengths of two strings of `x`s delimited by a `,`, specifying \$(n,k)\$. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method. It can yield outputs bigger than the input, and is really good at multiplying.)

This simply enumerates all the partitions. In order to count unordered partitions, it enforces that partitions occur in strictly nondecreasing order. This is accomplished by starting with an arbitrary-sized partition on the first iteration, then increasing it by an arbitrary nonnegative integer on each subsequent iteration. Each iteration increments the counter, which is then compared with \$k\$ at the end.

On each iteration, the size of the partition (arbitrarily chosen) is captured in `\1`, which is accessed via a nested backreference. The counter is stored in `\2`. Lookinto is used to ensure there is room to read and increment `\2` on each iteration.

```
^                   # tail = N
(                   # \1 = the following, looping:
    (?^=            # Lookinto; tail = N
        (           # \2 = sum of the following:
            \2?     # previous value of \2 if set, else 0
            x       # 1
        )
    )
    # \1 = the sum of the below items
    (
        \1          # On subsequent iterations, \1
    |
        ^x          # On the first iteration, 1
    )
    x*              # any nonnegative integer
    # \1 = some of the above items
)+                  # Iterate the above as many times as possible, min 1
,                   # Assert tail == 0; tail = K
\2$                 # Assert tail == \2
```

This uses nested backreferences (supported by Java / Perl / PCRE / .NET), a branch reset group (Perl / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>), and a **lookinto**, a feature just added to [RegexMathEngine](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine). The parameterless form of it, `(?^=pattern)`, is equivalent to one of the common uses of variable-length lookbehind, `(?<=(?=pattern)^.*)` – it allows matching against the entire string, even after the top-level cursor has advanced past the start. It also has a parametrized form, e.g. `(?^5=pattern)` will match `pattern` against the current contents of `\5`.

## Regex  ([RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/) / Perl / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
^((?|(?=.*,(\2x))\1x*|^(x)+))+,\2$
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Restricted-Integer-Partitions-PCRE2-v1035) (RegexMathEngine)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7LaoQwFAbgfZ8ihDPDOSZ4K7NoYwzCdNtVl6IUW2FQM0OYRYraV7epXXT188N3LrdPN5626YuBU2wer937yCBRoeriXL1V5foAky5K1V8dgtWZAltomEIIQTPYMjseb@5i77y2XLGdDb9sCMyG2Nnwz1hQ0OlUIXLPPViKueTxXxmI9HeC5hkcoTGzENDJdKXw0T7dM354/OASurBkCWfWtW1fXs9tuzWIZkGj40hinXuiOvPR0qAnQSRkncO25U8/) - Perl v5.28.2 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Rc7NSsNAEAfwu0-xLGOZ6a5pkx4UN5ulUK-ePIYGSQ1Ikm1ZKqwk8UW8FNEn8Sn6Nq6J4Ok_A7_5eP88PLnmdP5uXxk4xbpmXz42DBYqtDrdrB_W2XABrU4zVe0dgtWxAptqaEMIQR3YLJ7NDu7ZHnluuWIjq39ZHZgNMbL6n7GgoNRLhcg992Ap4pJHU1MT6bcFmltwhMZ0QkAplwOFj8bpivHL1Y5LKMOSPpwZhqK4u98UxdfLsbq6OfMtounR6GguMU88UR77eb9FT4JIyDyBSZ7-4iO5nqof) - Perl v5.36+
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVZfT9tIEH895Qvc6-Beya5tOBJ0FSIxiEIkkFqo0qDrNVDLOOvEir227HWBXvkk93I66R77gXqf5mb_OHESTmdhZ3Y889udmd-M-eNbmCdVKW9_GobfxtZOkocF6-4cWLffhy8mLIo5g3enw0HXP706G_jXlxcj_9eLs9E5HLRexDxMqgmDvnLanR21wllQgJ-Pb8GDofX6_n5-t1_99vj4YTR7dT8jf1ci2jn4bn0i5PgrOfZ2bZfcdB8ovek82F8_kQfqUOq4N92ftOU_P_xI10EsF-zc83On02ucoBRFzKfyCEtdnKGWBenRht1RK-YCchSFz4oiK0iY8VKAOr6dsrIMpozC76WYHB6GaAH9Phi1FJWe8UnSg4KJquDQ6T1tYMp1mE2YC3dZlkDmRUFSSli1jYEbd395ddtrAV5xBERl0p8yg-EbK6JxiC7F9en5yfDApualC2X8hWURWRz851rTsKeUql3kRTI41kGEWSXgEBaBUhmepdxAneAQrLXglbNloZd1wy26yEeENJrpSBZJaT21Kl7GU84mkGR8qh8BL-9Z0VMJSx_9MEgSPIaJ3az8uyQL52CHLnzO4gnYk0AEmDuZJCmC5wGRb2y6vcSgBttxFpXZM5VJg5gTBFAHzMdIhIRxktOdzq2319MhaHZAHnoWOT60eig5Xq5_LEqOT_HeoqivEHG_6wssKvpK-CkKCroJFPO8EtJdBYYlBLtg9ToNRDjzVSz2UtZoBSurRLi6BD3Tge8vPg6UJopKhi8xXgxhKmYrBnb2mYUCvUwlsBPr_dM8ThgxpHj_bjSkebgb-nhYQl2D8XEwvPJHg-Hbi8uT0eCsVg8-jAaXZ3K9rc5kfs1J9uiSwVsFEtDkvtkN6mnsGqF7G9nwcR0I5kdFlvp5IAQrOCmQ5ZfXb94YgKYPtq5gDwKTWEvec-8NLNlAwQgWFKwh3AYv3ed4tg6gt0riNG6C7HRor2E0Ybn4X6OChVVRxhl_1nBJMZwRCU5nols35q5mG9UESjEJgchiopR1kY2_HnMlmnB2r1fj1Ok4eJtRFGUFqPnFvU4PeN9L8ek4dfvUteZHHQqILyFI-4a3zQYrEHMJMe97HJ-rEDXMfAUGmiiKLSzFxJBSyi60H9oucAxz4yrHHEB-edpu-3kEhzsdgzA3icIOknnA6Oc4BMa4lAh7q_56qCi9ac1Vjil6NvuqdCUwNob6W3IbZVPOtRhlGjRyfw-2t80uW57pvuHwauhfXr09GZ2e0xVHRcNGm9WTQxQVW9uD4ddnLfsL74hYL_cn-G3VoWJyIjXPJb2WfK-vp9aq9PRfTYlNzBhZxrzZ7NpgsabNaalf4jxZDHMdHX5W9P8Hf_7V7WjpXw) - PCRE2 v10.40+
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbLbttGFF1XXzFmCmuGolxRbg1DNC24tgAbSOyAkdE0tkPQ1EgiTA4Jchg_Gm_7Ad12002X2fVn0mW_pHcepEhLRQWRmse95z7njH7_EmZxWYjHX4ThlyujH2dhTof9fePmq_dqRucRo-jtsTcZ-scXJxP_8vxs6v90djI9RfudVxEL43JG0YFU2lkedsJlkCM_u7pBLvKMH-_v7253y58fH99Pl3v3S_xnyef9_a_GR4zHn_HY3TEtfD18IOTafjA_f8QPpEdIz7oefqsk__5mm7wEMSxkZq6f9Wyn4UHB84gthAurtSiFVRokh2tyh52IcZTBkPs0z9MchykrOJLumwktimBBCfql4LPRKAQJdHCA9LIYynXKZrGDcsrLnCHbeV7DFPMwnVEL3aZpjFJ3HsSFgJVmNNzV8Ie9G6eD4BPNEZaZ9BdUY_haCiscrEpxeXx65O2bRG9aqIieaDrHtePfVSsNeUKItCI-OEVjFUSYlhyNUB0oEeEZUg1JD0bIeBG8VDYM0DKumUHqfMyhjZYqkjopnedOyYpowegMxSlbqFfAinuaOzJhyaMfBnEMbujY9cy_jdPwDpmhhT6l0QyZs4AHkDuRJDFErouw2DHJ9gqDaOxer67MQFcmCSKGAUA6mF1BI8SU4Yz07Rt34KgQVHegLHQNPB4ZDox6bqZ-DILHx_BsEVgvAXF36HMoKugK-AUMJHQTKGJZyYW6DAxKiMycVvMk4OHSl7GYq7FCy2lRxtxSJXD0CXx39mEiV-bzgsImxAshLPiyJWCmn2jIQUtXAk5iZT_Jophi3RTv3k49koU7oQ_OYmJpjA8T78KfTrw3Z-dH08lJtTx5P52cn4j5tvRJ_2pPBmTVwVs5NKDOffM0yLeWa4TurmXDh3nAqT_P08TPAs5pznAOXX5--fq1BmjqwNHl9IFDEquRu2lfw-I1FIigbsEKwmr0pbWpz14CKFNxlERNkL5NnIbQjGb8f4VyGpZ5EaVso6A0O09zJNnlqe5cYIwYuBqrgxwxS_UecaqOr8rzRBCsCwbC3WvWBdNPru3ILamxI5gDE9cdECQsR6ykzgoBjELPCbOKK4vVXu1VlhYg0LJc6TJ674O-hRgUKeBppI3qJkQ9oUyctp6gRVh9AVefNUlhgrUsw1mXADtYuGoSKD_ULsQFFFT7AZvi3UM2PEyYt8kGjCsQ6vXEnda1uu39Z0SB0ze5tjKcKLsNoxtNPbdmCU2gG3ABgjJh3YcuZA3KJb0RGApNeFU1QZUJ1gaG5IGQSjRc6DMMUVhyVTpRJVgwaoO8RiMms34LebtzlLgrKH3d33YZ0D-__oaAIxUTS_dqScVr7QMqz3aTlKBAMuSB_K6IAcb6LDQyJ5xXqAcDtL2tLWy5mrY878Lzzy_eHE2PT0k7Kw1uquiW5yVtYIvStnRager4Nlx_z__FUcBplOJVFOvcpwTqOWleHmoT6LW-25TfcMuqv0t__GVbdmdoDTvfw7MHjz2wdtXevw) - PCRE2 v10.40+ - test cases only

Without lookinto, there's still always room within \$k\$, accesible via lookahead, to count iterations.

Starting with a positive arbitrary-sized partition on the first iteration is done by `^(x)+`, which also initializes the counter to \$1\$. On subsequent iterations, `\1x*` advances by the sum of `\1` and any arbitrary nonnegative integer, which also gets captured in `\1`. At the end, `,` asserts that the cumulative sum is equal to \$n\$.

To enforce \$k\$ as the number of partitions, it starts by setting `\2` \$=1\$ on the first iteration with `^(x)+`. On subsequent iterations, `(?^=(\2x))` increments `\2` by \$1\$. Lookahead is used to avoid not having room for `\2`\$+1\$ when nearing the end of \$n\$. The Branch Reset Group `(?|`...`|`...`)` allows `\2` to be captured/recaptured in these two places.

```
^                   # tail = N
(                   # \1 = the following, looping:
    (?|             # Branch Reset Group
        # This alternative can only match on iterations after the first, because
        # it unconditionally matches \1 and \2.
        (?=         # Lookahead
            .*,     # tail = K
            (\2x)   # \2 += 1
        )
        \1x*        # \1 += {any nonnegative integer}; tail -= \1
    |
        ^           # Anchor to start, to only match on the first iteration.
        (x)+        # \2 = 1; \1 = {any nonnegative integer}; tail -= \1
    )
)+                  # Iterate the above as many times as possible, min 1
,                   # Assert tail == 0; tail = K
\2$                 # Assert tail == \2
```

## Regex  ([RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/) / Perl / PCRE2), 50 bytes

```
^((?=(?(3)(\3)))((?|(?=.*,(\4x))\2x*|^(x)+)))+,\4$
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Restricted-Integer-Partitions-PCRE2-all) (RegexMathEngine)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY49a8MwEIb3/gohruEuEs6Hk6GVZRFI104dRUxwGwi2lSA6qNjuX3ev7tDp5bl77uP@Edv91H0JiEb07a0@twJWhtEWx8PboRwfoLNFaS63iBDsxkAoLHQcSlEPodwsFvd4DZ/SB2nErDW/WsNa4Ji15l8TbEFt1wZRJpkgUCa1zP6gIbLfK3TPEAmd65WCWq9H4o/m6YuQj/m71FDzkoHPjGNVvbweq2o6ITqLDnNCnxMR48CVbKnR7xKR36blcMJEiptK@x1M0/bpBw) - Perl v5.28.2 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY7BSsNAEIbvPsWyjGWmG9M26UHdbEKhXj31GBokbUCSbMtSIZLEF_FSRJ_Ep-jbOCaCp3_-me-fmffP495V58t3_SrAadFWh_ypEjDTbE20Xm1WcX8FtYliXRwcgjULDTYyULMoRS3YeDGZHN2zPcnUSi0GrPzFSsYsy4CV_5hgCnIz14iykQ1Y8qUn_dGUROZthsk9OMIkaZWC3Jv3xB8N6ULI63AnPch5Scdn-j7LHh7XWfb1cipubi_BFjExmGBImIZExLbjjj_1MF02RGnQTLstNqR4qLx0CWPy_Ccfwd1Y_QA) - Perl v5.36+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVVtT9tIEP6eXzG4d2TXNhwJvQqRGEQhEkgtVGnQ9ZpQyzjrxIq9tux1gWv56@VmX5w4CaezwJmdnXl2n3lzmOd7szB8eTNlUcwZfDofDrr@@c3FwL@9vhr5f11djC7hqPUm5mFSTRn087Bg3f35SSucBwX4@fgOPBha7x8eFveH1d9PT19G83cPc/LyjZBTj5ySQ0omh5RSXP5Ezb7tksnbR0on3Uf75zfySB3cdNzJ299e6CaK5YKde37udHqNK5SiiPlM3mGlizPUsiA92bI7acVcQI6i8FlRZAUJM14KUPe3U1aWwYxR@FGK6fFxiBbQ74NRS1HpGZ8mPSiYqAoOnd7zFqZch9mUuXCfZQlkXhQkpYRVxxi4cffPd3e9FuATR0BUKP0ZMxi@sSIah@hc3J5fng2PbGo2XSjjf1gWkeXF/6g1DXuMqDpFPiSDU00izCoBx7AkSiU9S7mBusExWBvklbNloZc14RZdxiNKqnKumSyD0npuVbyMZ5xNIcn4TL8CXj6woqcClj75YZAkeA3D3az8@yQLF2CHLnzP4inY00AEGDsZJCmC5wGROzbdXWFQg@04y8wcmMykQcwJAqgL5mMshIRxktO9zp130NMUdHVAHnoWOT22eig5Xq5/LEpOz/F/h6K@QsTDri8wqegr4WcoKOgmUMzzSkh3RQxTCHbB6nUaiHDuKy72StZoBSurRLg6BT3Tgp@vvg6UJopKhpvIFynMxHzNwM6@s1Cgl8kEtmJ9fprHCSOmKD5/Gg1pHu6HPl6WUNdgfB0Mb/zRYPjx6vpsNLio1YMvo8H1hVzvqjuZX3OTA7qq4J0CC9DEvtkN6m3sGtS9rWj4uA4E86MiS/08EIIVnBRY5de3Hz4YgKYPtq5gjwKDWEvea/sGlmyhIINlCdYQbqMu3dfqbBNAH5XEadwE2evQXsNoynLxv0YFC6uijDP@quGqxHBGJDieiW7dmLu62qguoBSDEIgsJkpZJ9n46zFXoglnD3o1Tp2Og/9mFEVZAWp@ca/TA973Unw7Tt0@da75SYcC4ksI0p7wtjlgDWIhIRZ9j@N7HaKGWazBQBNFVQtLMTCklLIL7ce2Cxxpbj3lmAPIT0/bbb@O4HCnYxAWJlDYQTIOyH6BQ2CMS4lwsO6vh4rSm9ZcrzFVns2@Kl0JjI2h/la1jbJJ5wZHGQaN3D@A3V1zyo5num84vBn61zcfz0bnl7S1SbzZZvXkEEXFNs5g@PXZiP7SOyLW74dT/LZqqhicSM1zWV6req@f59a69PxfTYlNzBhZcd5udm2wXNPmtNSbOE@Ww1yzw8/KS7fzK4ySYFa@7CXKY@/oXw) - PCRE2 v10.33 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVZfb9s2EH8d_AX2yqhbTEpyFjtdEcRWjNQxkABtUqgO1tVOBUWmbMESJUhU7WzNJ9nLMGCP_UDdp9nxj2zZzjDBko7Hux_5O96d_MfXIIvLQtzeLAi-jo1WnAU57bROjftv7ospDSNG0buBO-x4g9vLoXd3cz3yfrm-HF2h08aLiAVxOaWoJ52O5ueNYO7nyMvG98hBrvF6uVw8nJS_Pj5-GM1fLef475KHrdNvnU8Y9x3cxycET04IITD8Apoj08aTlytCJp2V-eUTXhELJi178vIH5fnPd9-TXVDDRmbmeJnV7tZ2VPA8YjOxpY0uSkFL_eR8z-68ETGOMhC5R_M8zXGQsoIjScdMaFH4M0rQ7wWfnp0FYIF6PaTVQpR6yqZxF-WUlzlD7e7THqYYB-mU2ughTWOUOqEfFwJWLqPhxp2fX913GwiuKERYRtabUY3haSuscLA6mrvB1YV7ahI9aaMi-o2mIV5v_KdKU7OHyMpVxIVT1FckgrTk6AytiRJBz5BuSO7gDBk75KWzYYCXMWEGWccjhLSaKybroDSeGiUrohmjUxSnbKYePiuWNO_KgCWPXuDHMWxDc9cj7yFOgwUyAxt9TqMpMqc-9yF2IkhCRI6DsJgxyeEGg2hsy1qfzLE-mcSPGAYAucFsDIkQU4Yz0mrfO8ddRUFlB8oCx8D9M6MLkuVk6mUQ3B_AfUBAXwLiScfjcKjgK-BnIEjoOlDEspILd0kMjhCZOa3Gic-DuSe5mBtZoeW0KGNuqyPo6op8f_1xKDVhWFCYBL5AYcbnWwZm-pkGHLz0SUBlVusnWRRTrJPi_buRS7LgKPBgs5jYGuPj0L31RkP37fXNxWh4WamHH0bDm0sxPpR70m-9k2OyyeCDHBJQx75eDfKp7WrUnb1oeDD2OfXCPE28zOec5gznkOU3d2_eaIC6D5QupysOQawk57l5DYv3UIDBOgUrCLuWl_ZzebYLoJaKoySqg7TapFszmtKM_69RToMyL6KUPWu4STHoETF0a6xKN2K2yjaiEiiBIPg8jbBUVoes_VWbK8CE0aUajROrbcGtW1GY5kj2L-a0u4j1nASellWVT3XW7LxNEOALCNycsKZeYAtiISAWPYfBcxuigllswaA6iswWmkBgcCFkGzVXTRsxoLl3FWOGkPgSNe3m8wgWs9oaYaEDBRUk4gDsF9AExjAUCMfb_qqpSL0uze0ck-lZr6vCFsBQGPK3yW2Q9XHucBRhUMi9Y3R4qFc5cHT1ue6t693cvr0YDa7IlqNMw1qZVZ2D5yXdWYPC12cn-mvvEBs_nkzh26qoQnBC2c9Fem3yvbqeGtvS038VJRQxpXjDeb_YlcF6TOrdUk1CP1k3c8UOPivq_8Gff3XaSvoX) - PCRE2 v10.40+
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbLbttGFF1XXzFmCmuGolxJdg1DNC04tgAbSORAkdE0kkPQ1EgiTA4Jchg_Gm_7Ad12002X2fVn0mW_pHcepEhLRQVTmrlz77nPOfTvX_0kzDPxuEvf_zo12mHip7TXPjJuvo1fzekiYBS9OxsPe-7Z1fnQvR5dTtyfLs8nF-io8SpgfpjPKTqWRnurk4a_8lLkJtMb5KCx8fr-_u52P__58fHDZHV4v8J_5nzRPvrW-4TxwMEDvE_wbJ8QAtsvINkzLTw7eCBk1nswv3zCD6QFhy1rdvC9svz7u13yEtSwkJk4btLq2pWIMp4GbClCWsuCGKTUi0429E4aAeMogSV3aZrGKfZjlnEk0zEjmmXekhL0S8bn_b4PGuj4GGmxWEo5ZfPQRinlecpQ137ewBR7P55TC93GcYhiZ-GFmYCVbjTctPfj4Y3dQPAJFgjLyrpLqjFcrYUVDlatuT67OB0fmUQfWigLnmi8wGXgPxSSij5UVnoRHxyjgUrCj3OO-qhMlIj0DGmGZAR9ZLxIXhobBlgZM2aQsh4LGKuVyqQsSuO5kbMsWDI6R2HMlurLY9k9TW1ZsOjR9b0whDB07nrn3oaxf4dM30Kf42COzLnHPaidKJJYIsdBWJyYZHeNQTR2q1V2pqM7E3kBwwAgA0ymMAghZTgh7e6N07FVCmo6UOI7Bh70DRtWLSdRPwbBgzN4dgjIc0Dc77kcmgq2An4JCwldBQpYknNhLhODFiIzpcU-8ri_cmUu5nqt0FKa5SG3VAtsfSPfX34cSslikVE4hHwhhSVf1RTM-DP1OVjpTsDNLPxHSRBSrIfi_bvJmCT-nu9CsJhYGuPjcHzlTobjt5ej08nwvBAPP0yGo3Ox35Ux6V8dSYesJ3gnhQHUta_eBvmt9SqpOxvVcGHvceou0jhyE49zmjKcwpSPrt-80QBVG7i6nD5wKGKxcrada1i8gQIZlCNYQFiVubS2zdlLAOUqDKKgCtLuEruiNKcJ_1-llPp5mgUx26oo3S7iFEl2eSonFxgjBO7G6iIHzFKzR-xi4ov2PBEEcsFAuDljTXD95HRteSQt9gRzYOI4HYKE54Dl1F4jgFOYOeFWcWW2PiujSuIMFGqeC1tG712wtxCDJnk8DrRTPYSoJYyJXbcTtAjSF3DlXZMUJljLMuxNDfCDRagmgfZD73ycQUN1HHAovluoCw8T7rtkC8YUlFot8Y5rWs36-TOiwOnbQls7jpTfitOtrp5ru4hGMA04A0VZsOZDE6oG7ZLRCAyFJqIqhqCoBKsDQ_FASRUaXvBzDFlYUiqDKAosGLVCXv0-k1W_hbrd2UrdEZS-GW-9DeifX39DwJGKiWV4pabitfoFlXe7SkrQIJlyR_6tiQHW-i5UKieCV6jHHbS7qz3sOJq2xuOrsTu6ens6Obsg9apUuKmgW57mtIItWluzqSWq89vy-nv-L44CTqMUr7PY5D6lUO5J9eWhDoFey3ebihvesurfpT_-6lrdRs_qNQ7gOYSn27H21dm_) - PCRE2 v10.40+ - test cases only

PCRE1, and PCRE2 up to v10.34, automatically makes any capture group atomic if it contains a nested backreference. To work around this, the capture is copied back and forth between `\2` and `\3` using only forward-declared backreferences.

This would also make the regex compatible with Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> and Ruby, but they have no way of doing  output without source code modifications.

It still doesn't work under PCRE1, probably due to its bug where in certain conditions, captures are not reverted to their earlier values when backtracking: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZRhb5swEIa/51dc2drYgVahqaYphEZd12kfsnaKUmlT0iLqGIICBhlYUrX968vOGNqkGQqOffieu3t9wLLsOGRs8yESLC7nHAYZk/xkcd5iC1@Cl03vwIWx8WW1Wj70yt@Pj78mi0@rBdncEzJ0yZD0KJn1KKW4fEbLSccis7M1pbPTdef5nqypiQ9Na3b2cUPfUwwLOpnrZabttN4yyIt5lKoUtk0yEuGuLUrRyv1kf995KxIFZDgtPC5lKglLRV5AVVIn4Xnuh5w@YZx@n@EGGAygtqppZediHjsgeVFKAbbz0ipFHoWCzyFORagHX@QrLp0qWvLoMT@O07IgSsFm4T3EKVtCh1F40ttN8xXbRWzl60eC4IYW4JVNsYiYC5LRY/vO7TqgE9KlQcZcgwz7hoMz0830n0HJ8BLvA4r2EpG9U6@AVDkrfoiTir0NikRWFspdcuhI7sC2RihKVkjtLXlexoWeKzWDIOeFBVgcZhkWC/0k/cNZkcpp706HQqoLWok0yaKYoywnzMPghFrw83J85X29mVyMRvCsV7eTb58tONKR9aQJ1aWaGQVADiSnjX5BdcQBwbJwtwWGAlU5SvAxpcodDud9OMxnAptti6nj1ODtE8O0385yS7aQF3EkONFdEwlLK0h1@Qm6@UUakcrYFFrjtaY5bhF8pVfTxLRNvGu1AsyYKI5wbQfEwE1wNM2mJ5rixblNAfkKQdoz0a4D7CCWCrEcuALHXUSDWe5gYJuiroQnKBHJ1dyC9rptgcAy9658KgDU56Fttf9PMIVp14RlLRT2jNIBq186SMClInR3/fWbUtnr9muaia85I5JbcH07GlmQWwqIHVL96h60oPeuIlW05gy6cHTUMA9c3XpX4/HN2Lu@@XExufxOW3t1VieuWgM/DsaVai9jl8/jnO@51c1pHPbm2Hq6JBQhCOIyX6g2SlX3vLq9tN7GQHKOCdPXL0X9DrZeNqf2XxbEfphvjmOlyD8)

```
^                      # tail = N
(                      # \1 = the following, looping:
    (?=
        (?(3)(\3))     # If \3 is set, \2 = \3, else leave \2 unset
    )
    (                  # \3 = the following, to avoid a nested backreference
        (?|            # Branch Reset Group
            # This alternative can only match on iterations after the first,
            # because it unconditionally matches \1 and \2.
            (?=
                .*,    # tail = K
                (\4x)  # \4 += 1
            )
            \2x*       # \3 = \2 + {any nonnegative integer}; tail -= \3
        |
            ^          # Anchor to start, to only match on the first iteration.
            (x)+       # \4 = 1; \3 = {any nonnegative integer}; tail -= \3
        )
    )
)+                     # Iterate the above as many times as possible, min 1
,                      # Assert tail == 0; tail = K
\4$                    # Assert tail == \4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ṄvL=∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuYR2TD3iiJEiLCIiLCI2XG4yIl0=)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒṗẈ=S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pz/c1WEb/P//f0OD/8YA)

Dang it, ninja'd by Kevin because I took the time to get the shortest jelly answer too :p

Exact same approach as the 05ab1e answer, derived independently - both answers get the integer partitions of the first input and then count the number of partitions where the length equals the second input.